# round integer number in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i am working with php round login i get some value from database and that value is like

> 1520000

now i want to round or conver into

> 1550000 or 1600000 using php

please help me

this is my code

```
function roundToTheNearestAnything($value, $roundTo)
{
$mod = $value%$roundTo;
return $value+($mod<($roundTo/2)?-$mod:$roundTo-$mod);
}

echo roundToTheNearestAnything(1520000, 10).'<br>';
```

Comment: Ok.. Lets see what you have tried.. Post your code..

Comment: i have update my question

Comment: What's your criteria? Why would you want to round 1520000 to 1550000 or 1600000? What logic or rules are you using to determine how to round?

Comment: i am new in php just let me know if its possible or not

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but your roundTo value wasn't right:

```
function roundToTheNearestAnything($value, $roundTo)
{
    $mod = $value % $roundTo;
    return $value + ( $roundTo - $mod );
}

echo roundToTheNearestAnything(1520000, 100000);
```

Except that this only always rounds up, but based on the expected values you were showing, it looks like that might be what you're after. It looks like the other person that answered must have thought the same thing. If you really want a function that rounds up or down, then this would work:

```
function roundToTheNearestAnything($value, $roundTo)
{
    $mod = $value % $roundTo;
    return ( $mod >= $roundTo / 2 )
        ? $value + ( $roundTo - $mod )
        : $value - $mod;
}

echo roundToTheNearestAnything(1520000, 100000);

echo '<br />';

echo roundToTheNearestAnything(1550000, 100000);

echo '<br />';

echo roundToTheNearestAnything(1570000, 100000);
```

Answer (score 0):

For $x you have to pass how many digits you want to round up.
if $n = 1560000 and $x=5000 you will get 1565000.

```
<?php
$n = 1520000;
echo roundUpToAny($n);
function roundUpToAny($n,$x=50000) {
    return round(($n+$x/2)/$x)*$x;
}
?>
```

**Input:** 1520000

**Output:** 1550000

**Input:** 1560000

**Output:** 1600000

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, my previous version only rounded to decimal places, so...

```
function roundTo ( $number, $round ){
    return round($number/$round)*$round;
}
echo roundTo(1520000, 50000).PHP_EOL;
echo roundTo(1560000, 50000).PHP_EOL;
echo roundTo(1590000, 50000).PHP_EOL;
echo roundTo(1520000, 100000).PHP_EOL;
echo roundTo(1490000, 100000).PHP_EOL;
```

gives...

```
1500000
1550000
1600000
1500000
1500000
```

If you want it to always round up - then replace `round` with `ceil`, if you always want it to round down, use `floor`.

Comment: @BrianGottier D'oh!  I've added a new version - caffeine and reading question does help.

Answer (score 0):

try below code,
if $value=1520000 and  $roundTo=30000 will give 1550000 and with $value=1520000 and  $roundTo=80000 will give u 1600000

```html
function roundToTheNearestAnything($value, $roundTo)
{
    $rounded_value = $value - ($value % 10 - $roundTo);
    return $rounded_value;
}


echo roundToTheNearestAnything(1520000, 30000);
```